# Reload Quote In Controller Action

Tags: cart, ajax

I have a custom action which I use to adjust some options for products.  This is done from the cart with an AJAX request.  I'd like to be able to just return the adjusted item's HTML and update that table row.  I can successfully edit the cart item options; however, when rendering that item no options show up in the returned HTML.  If I refresh the page, then the options appear.

Is there any way I can "refresh" or "reload" the quote within the cart and session?  I've tried the following code after I've done my cart edits and before I start the layout rendering.

```
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cart->getQuote()->getId());

    $cart->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
    $this->_getSession()->replaceQuote($quote);
    $cart->setQuote($quote);
    $cart->init();
```

That does not sufficiently reload the quote so that the Cart block uses the updated quote.

**UPDATE:** It appears that the only issue is the item options not showing up, not that it's not showing the updated cart.  It's just custom options that are added which aren't showing up.  So the real question seems to be reloading options for quote items.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you have replace c`urrent quote and items and other data`  at session class **checkout/session**    `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` using function `replaceQuote()` .

As per as magento,the `session variable does not affective` until one `time page rendered` and `cart block content depend on checkout session`.
So you need to rendered the page and update cart block content via ajax.

Comment: I have adjusted the code to load the layout prior to me editing the cart; however, it will not show the updates.

I have the following at the beginning of my controller action:

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->generateXml();
    $this->getLayout()->generateBlocks();

I then do my edits and render the blocks necessary capturing the HTML output.